# Facebook sharer.php requires multiple Share Link button clicks or a cache refresh to successfully submit

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-sharer

**Description:**

This problem began sometime around Thursday October 4, 2012.

HTTP trace shows response code 500 - Internal Server Error from www.facebook.com/ajax/sharer/submit_page/.

Repeated button clicks sometimes clear the problem, otherwise a cache refresh using developers.facebook.com/tools/debug for the shared URL is required.

We use the following "flavor" of sharer.php:

http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[medium]=103&p[url]=url&p[images][0]=imageUrl&p[summary]=summaryText&p[title]=titleText

**Example shortened share links:**

- http://on.fb.me/RiDHzy
- http://on.fb.me/OaHFwh
- http://on.fb.me/VFNSCd

You can tweak the value of the p[url]=url ta_pid querystring parameter to bust the FB cache.

**Expected Behavior**

- Share This Link page is displayed.
- Click Share Link button.
- Link is shared to your Facebook timeline.

**Actual Behavior**

- Share This Link page is displayed.
- Click Share Link button.
- Nothing visible happens.
- HTTP trace shows response code 500 - Internal Server Error from www.facebook.com/ajax/sharer/submit_page/.
- Repeated Share Link button clicks sometimes cause link to share successfully.
- After a cache refresh using developers.facebook.com/tools/debug for the shared URL -- p[url] -- clicking the Share Link button will cause link to share successfully.

Comment: It appears that Facebook has fixed this problem after escalation through multiple channels.  I will close out the question tomorrow if the problem does not reappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Facebook has fixed this problem after escalation through multiple channels.